# How does self.class.method work when including a module?

Tags: ruby

I am using HTTParty, and based on the docs you can create a class :

```
class SomeClass 
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'host'
    def index 
        self.class.get('/path')
    end
end
```

I am not sure how is `get` method declared inside the module.

Comment: module provides the class singleton methods, this is how you get `self.class.get` working

Comment: **tl;dr** - [`included` hook](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L19-L26).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get` method is defined at [line 484 of `httparty/httparty.rb`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/247d541f93e27d96e8226ec222a0c488886d1017/lib/httparty.rb)

```
def get(path, options = {}, &block)
  perform_request Net::HTTP::Get, path, options, &block
end
```

This is defined on a module called `ClassMethods`. If you look further up the file `httparty/httparty.rb`. At line 20 you will see:

```
def self.included(base)
  base.extend ClassMethods
```

The [method `included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-included) is called when a Module is included into another Module or Class.

This code ensures that when the `HTTParty` module is included into another module or class, the methods defined in `HTTParty::ClassMethods` are extended (added as class methods) onto the host object. They become class methods.